# ISR for Timer Compare Match not running

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, atmega

so basically I'm trying set up a ISR(Interrupt subroutine) to simply turn a light on, but the ISR doesn't seem to run. I've looked through the microcontroller datasheet a lot to see if I'm doing something wrong but I couldn't find anything.

Heres my code.

```
#include <asf.h>

int main (void) {
    DDRD = 0b10000000;

    cli();                              // turn off global interrupts
    //Timer
    TCCR2A |=_BV(WGM21);                //CTC mode
    TCCR2B |=_BV(CS22)|_BV(CS21);       //clk pre-scale 1/256
    OCR2A = 0x7d;                       //125clk cycles = 2ms
    TIMSK2 |=_BV(OCIE2A);               //enable interrupt on compare matchA
    TIFR2 |= _BV(OCF2A);                //clear flag
    TCNT2 = 0x00;                       // reset counter
    sei();                              // enable global interrupts
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect) {
    PORTD = 0b10000000;
}
```

Comment: Are you clearing the interrupt flag in your ISR?

Comment: does it work when you poll it with interrupts off (not the interrupt but everything else, clearing of the flags, etc)?

Answer (score 4):

You should have an endless loop at the end of your main() function:

```
#include <asf.h>

int main (void) {
    DDRD = 0b10000000;

    cli();                              // turn off global interrupts
    //Timer
    TCCR2A |=_BV(WGM21);                //CTC mode
    TCCR2B |=_BV(CS22)|_BV(CS21);       //clk pre-scale 1/256
    OCR2A = 0x7d;                       //125clk cycles = 2ms
    TIMSK2 |=_BV(OCIE2A);               //enable interrupt on compare matchA
    TIFR2 |= _BV(OCF2A);                //clear flag
    TCNT2 = 0x00;                       // reset counter
    sei();                              // enable global interrupts
    while(1);
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect) {
    PORTD = 0b10000000;
}
```

Without endless loop your AVR reaches an undefined state!

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem, it works now.

Comment: _Without endless loop your AVR reaches an undefined state!_ -- it isn't true. The state is pretty much defined: interrupts are disabled and infinite loop is executed.